# Manage slugs with PHP and .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slug

Let's call my site:

```
www.example.com
```

and I have a PHP file like this:

```
www.example.com/product.php?id=50
```

I would like to access it by using

```
www.example.com/product/50
```

but ALSO, very important, I have several subdirectories like

```
www.example.com/subsite/product.php?id=50
www.example.com/subsubsite/product.php?id=50
```

That must become

```
www.example.com/subsite/product/50
www.example.com/subsubsite/product/50
```

How can I solve it at best with PHP and `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite?
I banged my head with other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) but to no avail.

I can't seem to find a solution that works flawlessly, taking care of all imported files like CSS, JS and PHP classes.

Comment: Please post what you tried and think is the more correct so we can check what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this might not be the complete answer but should help you find your way.

You can use regex to match your desired path pattern. So for example your htaccess might look something like...

```
# Check if module is installed
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check query for matching pattern and pass id, but also append additional query strings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+\/)?product\/([0-9]+)$ /$1product.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

# If not file or directory on server, send to 404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

---

And what this does is...

**1. Match the uri with a regex pattern**

Regex: `^([^\/]+\/)?product\/([0-9]+)$`

1. `^` - Start of string.
2. `([^\/]+\/)?` - matches any directory (if exists) and stores it for reuse.
3. `product\/([0-9]+)` - Your desired path e.g. `product/50` and stores the number "id" for reuse.
4. `$` - End of string.

**2. Pass captured directory and id to our file**

Like so: `/$1product.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]`

1. `$1` is our directory name including the trailing slash e.g. `subsubsite/`
2. `$2` is our product id e.g. `50`
3. `[L,QSA]` The QSA flag means we can access additional query string parameters e.g. `/product/50?show=all&updated=1`. More about flags can be found here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

**3. 404 anything not matching**

Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.php [L]
```

1. `!-f` If request is not a file
2. `!-d` If request is not a directory
3. `/404.php` The file used for presenting a 404 error.

---

Getting the id...

With the above, you can get the ID within your `product.php` file like so:

```php
$id = (int)$_GET[ 'id' ];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working, in the sense that all included files are not loaded.

Comment: @AlanPiralla try my updated answer (including `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` above the RewriteRule)

Comment: Nice explanation. Although the 2nd rule that rewrites to `404.php` does not seem to be a requirement here? (_Aside:_ To implement a 404 "error document", you should simply use `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` instead, which also handles the correct HTTP status.)

Comment: It's still not working.
All included file are imported like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">`
But in the consoles all imported files give me a 404 since they are rewritten like this:
`www.example.com/product/css/main.css`